# How to discard files from the Xtext indexing process?

Tags: eclipse, indexing, out-of-memory, eclipse-cdt, xtext

I have built an Xtext based editor for our DSL which works fine, but we get an out of memory error while the workspace is building or when we force a project cleaning. Our DSL plug-in is used in conjunction with the Eclipse CDT to build microcontrollers test programs. A test program project is made of C++ files and ".xxx" files for which I have built the DSL editor. The out of memory error occurs when the test program project contains at least one large ".xxx" file (~300 Mbyte). We don't even open this large file, we simply clean the project and the memory error occurs.

This seems to be an Xtext indexer issue. Is there a way to tell the Xtext indexer to ignore ".xxx" files located in a particular folder of the project? I have read several times the Scoping chapter of the excellent "Implementing DSLs with Xtext and Xtend" from Lorenzo Bettini, but did not find any solution to this issue. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the extension points for this are `org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceServiceProvider.canHandle(URI)` or `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.resource.IResourceUIServiceProvider.canHandle(URI, IStorage)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian, you helped me one more time ! Although I did not find how to manage properly the protocolName field of the org.eclipse.xtext.protocol_resourceServiceProvider, I could filter out files located in a particular folder of my projects by checking the URI parameter of the canHandle function.